# How to create ListView with custom rows in Xamarin widget

Tags: android, listview, xamarin.android, widget

I need some help in updating my xamarin widget listview with custom rows.
I found some example, but it doesn't work until now.
This is my code.

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Label = "@string/widget_name")]    
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" })]
[MetaData("android.appwidget.provider", Resource = "@xml/widget_word")]

public class WordWidget : AppWidgetProvider
{
   public override void OnUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager  appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)      
   {
      int N = appWidgetIds.Length;
      for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
       {
            RemoteViews remoteViews = updateWidgetListView(context, appWidgetIds[i]);

             appWidgetManager.UpdateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], remoteViews);
        }
            base.OnUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }
     private RemoteViews updateWidgetListView(Context context, int appWidgetId)
     {
            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.PackageName, Resource.Layout.widget_word);

            Intent svcIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(WidgetService));

            svcIntent.PutExtra(AppWidgetManager.ExtraAppwidgetId, appWidgetId);
            svcIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(svcIntent.ToUri(IntentUriType.Scheme)));           
            remoteViews.SetRemoteAdapter(appWidgetId, Resource.Id.listViewWidget, svcIntent);
            remoteViews.SetEmptyView(Resource.Id.listViewWidget, Resource.Id.empty_view);

            return remoteViews;
       }
   }
```

base.OnUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds); --> on this row my app widget crashes

my UpdateWidget service:

```
[Service(Permission = "android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS", Exported = false)]
public class WidgetService : RemoteViewsService
{
    public override IRemoteViewsFactory OnGetViewFactory(Intent intent)
    {            
        int appWidgetId = intent.GetIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.ExtraAppwidgetId,
        AppWidgetManager.InvalidAppwidgetId);

        return (new ListWidgetProvider(this.ApplicationContext, intent));
    }

}

public class ListWidgetProvider : RemoteViewsService.IRemoteViewsFactory
{
    private Intent intent;

    List<MarketDataParams> DataList = new List<MarketDataParams>();
    private Context context = null;
    private int appWidgetId;

    public ListWidgetProvider(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.intent = intent;
        appWidgetId = intent.GetIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.ExtraAppwidgetId, AppWidgetManager.InvalidAppwidgetId);
    }


    public bool HasStableIds
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public RemoteViews LoadingView
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public int ViewTypeCount
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
           return DataList.Count();
        }
    }

    private void populateListItem()
    {                      

    }


    public long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public RemoteViews GetViewAt(int position)
    {
        WidgetData wd = new WidgetData();
        string w_data = wd.GetSecurities();
        string f_data = wd.GetUserFivoritList();
        ArrayList listItemList = new ArrayList();

        MarketData secData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MarketData>(w_data);
        MarketData fivData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MarketData>(f_data);
        var updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.PackageName, Resource.Layout.widget_word);

     if (secData.data.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in secData.data)
            {
                MarketDataParams DataParams = new MarketDataParams();
                DataParams.Name = item.Name;
                DataParams.Fields.LastDealRate = item.Fields.LastDealRate;
                DataParams.Fields.DailyNISRevenue = item.Fields.DailyNISRevenue;
                DataParams.Fields.BaseRateChangePercentage = item.Fields.BaseRateChangePercentage;
                DataParams.Id = item.Id;
                DataList.Add(DataParams);
            }

        }

        updateViews.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.blog_title,DataList[0].Name);
        updateViews.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.creator, DataList[0].Fields.BaseRate);

        return updateViews;
    }

    public void OnCreate()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnDataSetChanged()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnDestroy()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/Nailik/AppWidgetListView - good example for implementing ListView

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks a lot.